# SQL - Left Join many-to-many only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables that are setup like the following examples

tablea

```
ID | Name
1  | val1
1  | val2
1  | val3
2  | other1
3  | other
```

tableb

```
ID | Amount
1  | $100
2  | $50
```

My desired output would be to left join tableb to tablea but only join tableb once on each value. ID is the only relationship

```
tablea.ID | tablea.Name | tableb.id | tableb.amount
1         | val1        | 1         | $100
1         | val2
1         | val3
2         | other1      | 2         | $50
3         | other
```

Microsoft SQL

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables ? Tablea.id = tableb.id ?

Comment: tablea.id = tableb.id is the only relationship.

Comment: which RDBMS ar eyou using ? Sql Server ? mySql ?

Comment: Your desired output does not appear to be possible with the table structure.  If all you have to join ion is ID then you don't have a way to determine which of the 3 records with the same id the amount should go to. You need to revisit your data model to fix this.

Comment: Microsoft SQL, sorry should have specified

Comment: I only have read permissions to the database, so unfortunately have no control over the db structure.

Comment: Then your task cannot be done. It is physically not possible without knowing what record is related to the amount.

Comment: Then you MUST specify which row in tableA you wish to join to. If there are more than one row in the other table, How can the query processor know which one you want ?

Comment: I agree, but wasn't sure if there was a way to only select the relationship once and only join it once then stop and move on to the next ID.

Comment: do you want to join on the `min` of some field, like the `min(name)`?  Aggregation may be all you need...

Comment: Certainly possible, as my example wasn't good with the amounts.. . There are never duplicates in tableb. so it could always be the Min.

Comment: I'd rather not place aggregation on tablea as I have a large number of column names I'm selecting, and since I'd have to place every single column in the group by clause it could get messy real quick. I have over 100 columns on the production side.

Comment: your expected outcome doesn't include join results for ID 2. is this on purpose?

Comment: @sarin I figured it had enough information to answer the question, edited to include complete outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowID ASC) as RowNum, ID , Name
from tablea
```

which gives you :

```
RowNum | RowID | Name
1      | 1     | val1
2      |1      | val2
3      |1      | val3
4      |2      | other1
5      |3      | other
```

You then get the minimum row number for each RowID:

```
Select RowId, min(RowNum)
From (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowID ASC) as RowNum, ID , Name
    from tablea )
Group By RowId
```

Once you have this you can then join tableb onto tablea only where the RowId is the minimum

```
WITH cteTableA As (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowID ASC) as RowNum, ID , Name
    from tablea ), 

cteTableAMin As (
    Select RowId, min(RowNum) as RowNumMin
    From cteTableA
    Group By RowId
    )
Select a.RowID, a.Name, b.Amount
From cteTableA a
Left join cteTableAMin amin on a.RowNum = amin.RowNumMin
                            and a.ID = amin.RowId
Left join tableb b on amin.ID = b.ID
```

This can be tidied up... but helps to show whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Then you MUST specify which row in tableA you wish to join to. If there are more than one row in the other table, How can the query processor know which one you want ?

If you want the one with the lowest value of `name`, then you might do this:

```
Select * from tableB b
    join tableA a
       on a.id = b.Id
          and a.name =
             (Select min(name) from tableA
              where id = b.id)
```

but even that won't work if there multiple rows with the same values for both `id` AND `name`.  What you might really need is a Primary Key on tableA.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select
  a.id,
  a.name,
  b.amount
from
   (select
      id,
      name,
      row_number() over (partition by id order by name) as rn
      from tablea) a
left join (
    select
      id,
      amount,
      row_number() over (partition by id order by amount) as rn
    from tableb) b
  on a.id = b.id
    and a.rn = b.rn
order by a.id, a.name
```